# How to output Core Data into Array to Produce Graph (Swift)

Tags: swift, core-data, xcode6

i want to display a graph based on the data from my Core Data. How can do this?

```
var myArray: Array <Float> = [0]

let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "StudentCGPA")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;
    var results:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!
    if results.count > 0 {
        for student in results{
            var thisstudent = student as StudentCGPA

      'the fetched data should output to myArray

        }
    }else {

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fill your new array with floats, just do:

```
myArray.append(thisstudent.yourFloatEntity)
```